# Can a Gloom Stalker ranger benefit from the Stalker's Flurry feature with a ranged weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, ranged-attack

The description of the [Gloom Stalker ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#GloomStalker)'s 11th-level Stalker's Flurry feature (XGtE, p. 42) says:

> At 11th level, you learn to attack with such unexpected speed that you can turn a miss into another strike. Once on each of your turns when you miss with a **weapon attack**, you can make **another weapon attack** as part of the same action.

I am having trouble finding an answer anywhere on whether Stalker's Flurry works with ranged weapons or not.

I would like RAW, RAI, and maybe personal ruling for an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Since it doesn't specify: *either* a ranged *or* a melee weapon attack

It works for either a ranged or melee weapon attack, but it will not work for a spell attack.

If there were a restriction on weapon type, then you'd see additional qualifying text, such as what you see in the [Hunter ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Hunter)'s 11th-level **Multiattack** feature (PHB p. 93):

> **Volley**. You can use your action to make *a ranged attack* against any number of creatures within 10 feet of a point you can see within your weapon’s range.   {specifies ranged attack}
>
> **Whirlwind Attack**. You can use your action to make *a melee attack* against any number of creatures within 5 feet of you, with a separate attack roll for each target. {specifies melee attack}

The Gloom Stalker feature is more like the Hunter ranger's 3rd-level **Hunter's Prey** feature (PHB p. 93):

> **Colossus Slayer**. Your tenacity can wear down the most potent foes. *When you hit a creature with a weapon attack* [...]
>
> **Giant⁠ Killer**. When a Large or larger creature within 5 feet of you hits or misses you with an attack, you can use your reaction *to attack that* creature immediately after its attack [...]
>
> **Horde Breaker**. Once on each of your turns *when you make a weapon attack*, you can make another Attack with the same weapon against a different creature [...]

A table anecdote: a friend of mine plays a Gloom Stalker Ranger in our tier 3 game.  He has the Sharpshooter feat.  Those two fit together to make him scary good at inflicting damage on the enemies.

Answer (score 3):

## Any attack with a weapon qualifies

You quoted the relevant part, it is in no way restricted to *melee* weapons.

There are no quotes other than this.

Comment: 16 seconds slower

Comment: Yeah, great minds think alike. :)